# Significance of two different img's in the given code?

Tags: javascript

[It is a link to w3schools Website for a JS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb)

In the above program I found that there are two src's of image in the ( if loop ) i.e. `img src="pic_bulboff.gif"` and `img src= "pic_bulbon.gif"`. Why is there a need for two `img src's`? 
What is the use of "match" in this program?

Comment: It's an if/else statement. Clicking on the image triggers the Javascript function which switches between the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` attribute is the URL for the image - it's what gets displayed.  That's not a loop, it's an `if` statement - a branching or conditional statement - and only one of the branches will be taken each time the function is called.  It is a toggle - when you click the light, it switches the `src` attribute to the one not currently selected.

`match` is a [function on a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that takes a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). If you are just getting started programming, that's a deep rabbit hole to go down, but basically it's checking whether the current `src` attribute value contains that text or not.

Comment: What is meant by a loop ? What is the difference between a Statement and a Loop ??

Comment: A loop does things more than once.  An `if` statement is just a one-off.  So a `for` loop, for example, will do something `n` times: `for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) { console.log(i); }` will log the variable `i` to the console 50 times.

Comment: Ok. So the loop can be used infinite times ? What are the applications of loop ? Is it used in advanced version of JS ? Are there any other loops in other programming languages ?

Comment: It's one of the fundamental constructs of computation - iteration - being able to do the same thing to a bunch of different items.  `for`, `while` `do/while` are the main forms in JS, C.  Recursion is another, loosely speaking.  I'd start with something like http://eloquentjavascript.net/, or even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: The links are helpful !

Answer (score 0):

It is checking if the image is the bulbon image, if it is then it changes it to the bulboff image and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question let's look at the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>

<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As the problem states, the whole point is to change`<img>` src attribute upon clicking the `<img>` tag.

That implies that if the light is on, meaning if the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag contains the word **off**, we want to change the `src` to be `src="pic_bulbon.gif"`. This should work like a normal light bulb, on and off. Each image represents a bulb that is off or a bulb that is on.

**[Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** is the key to the solution. What match does is that it will look at a string and find a word within that string, if such word exists then it will return true.

Using match on the string from the `src` attribute will help us to find a the word **on** or **off*. So considering what the `src` attribute contains, pic_bulb**on**.gif or pic_bulb**off**.gif, we will match like so in JavaScript:

`stringName.match(someOtherString)`, which translates to `image.src.match("bulbon")` or `image.src.match("bulboff")` conversely.

After this we can set the `src` attribute to **on** or **off** via the if/else statement:

```
if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
    image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
} else {
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
}
```

If you still have any questions please ask in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code is doing: [Working Example with logging](https://jsbin.com/divihan/7/edit?js,console)

```
function changeImage() {
  // grab the element (in this case an img tag) using the id 'myImage'
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  // check to see if the source of the image contains the word 'bulbon'
  // match return an array of matches
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
      // if there is a match for bulbon change the image src to pic_bulboff.gif
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
      // if not change it to pic_bulbon.gif
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}


// on match:


var s = 'aaaabulbonaaa';

var matchResult = s.match('bulbon');
  // match return an array of matches
console.log(matchResult); // ["bulbon"]
```

Comment: What is the precise meaning of " grab the image using the id 'myImage' " ?

Comment: thats what document.getElementById does, it grabs the element, might not be an image, you're right will edit

Comment: So it is mandatory for one two download two different images of the bulb { here in this case it is the Bulboff and Bulbon } and then use the image.src to link to two different images in the above code, right ?